# How to Select then Insert in phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql

How can I correctly do select then insert the result in the $result?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT AVG(answervalue) 
                        FROM `tblanswer` 
                        WHERE questiontype = 'Methods' 
                         AND studentid = '$username' 
                         AND subjectname = '$server_subject' 
                         AND professorname = '$server_name', $connect);

$Query = "INSERT INTO tblevaluationgrade (result) VALUES ('$result')";
```

Comment: you have an obvious syntax error, IF that's your real code.

Comment: Also note that `AVG` is not going to do much without a `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: PHPMyAdmin *is not* a database. It is a web interface for your MySQL database.

Comment: Please [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). [These extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.removed-exts-sapis.php) have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) and [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and consider using PDO, [it's really pretty easy](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your query should be like:

```
INSERT INTO tblevaluationgrade(result_column) 
   (SELECT AVG(answervalue) FROM `tblanswer`   
     WHERE questiontype = 'Methods' AND studentid = '$username'   
       AND subjectname = '$server_subject' AND professorname = '$server_name')
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do that in one query using [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tblevaluationgrade (result)
    SELECT AVG(answervalue) FROM `tblanswer` ...
```

And you should probably switch to PDO or mysqli and prepared statements as the `mysql_*` functions are deprecated *and* have been removed from php 7 and your query looks vulnerable to sql injection.

Comment: Let's only hope they know what to do about their present syntax error ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Yes, it is not going to work like this but to answer the direct question...

Comment: That was just *"my 2 cents"* ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- Freed my answer from any potential problems by just showing the valid stuff ;-)